# 301 redirect new domain to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

There are 2 domains and .htaccess 301 redirect with masking:

```
    RewriteEngine On <br/>
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example.com\.com$ [NC] <br/>
    RewriteRule ^ http://foo.bar%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It shows the same content for both domains.
How can I set 301 redirect [www.foo.bar](http://www.foo.bar) to [www.example.com/index.php/fr/](http://www.example.com/index.php/fr/) and show only www.foo.bar/index.php/fr/ when www.foo.bar is typed?
It is joomla installation so the other pages (/index.php/fr/blah-blah) should be redirected as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a redirect you should use 'redirect' ...

# seo friendly redirect for a single file

Redirect 301 /old-dir/old-file.html http://domain.com/new-dir/new-file.html

A good read is [THE htaccess reference page](http://perishablepress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to reword your question but if you are using rewrite then simplest method is:

RewriteBase /fr

are you trying to setup a separate version of your joomla in French?  If so why not just use the built in language capabilities of Joomla?  There are extensions for this purpose as well.

Here is the link to the joomla extension directory for multilingual content: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content